# Is there a way to replicate a preconfigured ubuntu os?

Tags: operating-system, embedded-linux, production-environment, system-administration

I am trying to replicate an ubuntu OS which is has (NAT,Firewall etc) setup.I am trying to find away to install a preconfig os or the os image in production, to avoid installing and setting up manually in each and every machine.Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: You should take care to choose better keywords. There is nothing about "linux kernel" and probably "operating system" is too much. In any case, there is a way (probably uyou should check Debian documentation). Your task is common (e.g. in schools). Unfortunately I doesn't remember. Maybe ServerFault site (one of our sister site, links in the top right icon) is more relevant for such questions (but look if there is already an answer to that question)

Comment: Well i couldnt find one

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come to mind--both variations on a theme. There may be other better methods that others know of, but lets at least start with the following.

Method #1. Assuming that the hardware is exactly the same between systems, you may be able to copy an install from one disk to another (or clone it using 'dd').

Method #2. If you are using virtual machines, you may have a master copy that you copy as needed (instead of identical hardware, you have identical virtual hardware).

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, Yes I am using the same hardware it's an Intel Atom on a development board. How do I clone it as it as an in-build memory rather than an SSD which most single board PC use.